# How can I make a play two musical notes simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, playback, music-notation

I plan to do a music notation which allow the user to place the note where ever they want and allowed them to play the notes they placed.

If the user put the note in the same time which we have to play 2 or above notes together, any solution to solve that problem?

Comment: How are you playing the notes?

Comment: I tried pygame and winsound.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is really simple and straightforward in theory - use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). Your code has to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: I have the same issue as Jun Ming, however, using threads does NOT work, as I have tested. Any other solutions? Thanks. If you need my code, I can provide it, but I can confirm I have done everything right.

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiprocess` and `winsound` module to do so.

Comment: if I have:  winsound.Beep(261,999) #C notes  winsound.Beep(293,999) # D notes  .How can i play it together with multiprocess

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
....
....
....
threading.Thread(name='<thread_name>', target='<your_target>').start()
```

you can do it 2 times for 2 different targets

Comment: as I said to PatNowak I have the same issue as Jun Ming, however, using threads does NOT work, as I have tested. Any other solutions? Thanks.